# jQuery - Proper way to rebind existing function after new item added to DOM

Tags: jquery

I want to rebind existing function after an draggbale item dropped, like:

`.item` are draggable item, and `.droppable` is droppable area.

I am running a function for `.droppable`s  `.item` on `.ready()`, but if I drop an `.item` to `.droppable` then my existing function will not work for newly dropped `.item`, So I put my event inside a function, like:

```
function my_event(){
    jQuery('.droppable').on('mouseover.mine mouseout.mine', function (e) {
            if ($(this).is(".active")) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery(this).toggleClass('highlight');
            }
        }).on('click.mine', function(e){
            if ($(this).is(".active")) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                show_data(this);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Now, I can simply call this function on `.ready()` and for `.droppable()` event `stop`.
It is working fine,

**but I want to ask is it right to call and rebind the function after every `.item` dropped ?
if no then please tell me how to do this in a proper way.**

Comment: What event are you binding to on .item?  Rather than binding directly to each element with .item, you could let the event bubble up and handle it in a parent container.

Comment: Dear @dc5, Yes it is working when added to parent after. looking below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 'right' or 'wrong' way to do most things, though there are more efficient methods. The solution you need is delegated event handling, where the events are handled once they've propagated to the parent element, thereby getting rid of the need to rebind the handler for new child elements.

Let's say all of your `.droppable` elements are contained in a `.parent` element, and new ones will be added there.

Your handler would look like

```
jQuery('.parent').on('mouseover.mine mouseout.mine', '.droppable', function (e) {
    if ($(this).is(".active")) {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

The [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/on) for `on` will be helpful in understanding this logic.

### Update

As I note in my comment, the rest of your code will have to adjust for this change, since `e.stopPropagation();` is by definition at odds with the concept of a delegated event. Your current approach would have to be re-tooled to something like

```
jQuery('.parent').on('mouseover.mine mouseout.mine', '.droppable', function (e) {

    // get the original child which triggered event
    var activeElem = $(e.target).closest('.droppable');

    if ($(activeElem).is(".active")) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(activeElem).toggleClass('highlight');
    }
}
// etc
```

If you've never used them, read up on [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) and [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

Comment: The specific section on direct vs. delegated events is http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: @user007 No problem. Remember that you will need to reference the parent element, whatever it is, correctly. It's also a good idea to read the documentation here carefully to understand what's happening. Your code will have to change, because `e.stopPropagation();` is by definition at odds with the concept of a delegated event.

Comment: `click.mine` is not working on a `.item` which is a shortble, How to fix this ? thanks for help

Comment: I added  `.on('click.mine', '.droppable, .droppable .item', fn` but not working

Comment: Oh sorry, I was using `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`, removed it. :-D